# Parse.com Javascript update value by objectID

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I try to update a value in my Parse.com Core, but it simply does not work.
I have the "objectID" of the item that i want to update

```
 Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

    var PP = Parse.Object.extend("PP");
    var PP = new PP();

    var query = new Parse.Query(PP);
                        query.equalTo("objectId", "3Enwfu0QPQ");
                        query.first({
                            success: function (PP) {
                                PP.save(null, {
                                    success: function (PP) {

                                        PP.set("free", "100");


                                        PP.save();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
```

i want to set the value of "free" for object "3Enwfu0QpQ" to 100, but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several issues with your code:

1.

```
var PP = Parse.Object.extend("PP");
var PP = new PP();
```

According to your screenshot, the Class is named "P", not "PP". You are also overriding the PP object.

2.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(PP);
query.equalTo("objectId", "3Enwfu0QPQ");
query.first({[...]});
```

`query` is invalide because PP is no longer the PP object. You should also use [query.get](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects) instead of `equalTo`.

3.

```
PP.save(null, {
  success: function (PP) {
    PP.set("free", "100");
    PP.save();
  }
});
```

You are saving an empty object then editing this same object, then you update it again.

Your code should look like this (untested).

```
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

var P = Parse.Object.extend("P");

var query = new Parse.Query(P);
query.get('3Enwfu0QPQ', { // we get the object
  success: function (instance) {
    instance.set("free", "100"); // We update the returned object
    instance.save(); // we save it
  }
});
```

You can also save a request by doing so:

```
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

var P = Parse.Object.extend("P");

var instance = new P();
instance.id = '3Enwfu0QPQ';
instance.set("free", "100");
instance.save();
```

Comment: i just did try it but no success, it "joins" the success function but does not update the value for me 

seem to be a problem that it is a "number" and not a string thats why the "" should be removed

Comment: Did you have it working? I edited my answer to add a much simpler code.